# Is there a way to create two submittable HTML forms, one which contains and validates all fields of the other?

Tags: html

For example, I want to create two forms as follows:

formA is responsible for posting the content of `field1` using `formA_btn` and enforces validation of `field1`.

formB is responsible for posting the content of `field1` and `field2` using `formB_btn`, and enforces validation of `field1` and `field2`.

Witten another way, the user should be displayed the following:

- field1
- formA_btn <--- **should only check for field1 content**
- field2
- formB_btn <--- should check for both field1 and field2 content

I've set up a fiddle here to show my current attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/aleholland/ym0n96fk/12/

In my attempt, the behavior is more like the following undesirable configuration:

- field1
- formA_btn <--- **incorrectly checks for both field1 and field2 content**
- field2
- formB_btn <--- correctly checks for both field1 and field2 content

Comment: What is the use case for this? Are you essentially trying to send an *optional* piece of information? Because this seems like a question that assumes a solution to a problem that is already potentially going down the wrong approach.

Comment: Hmm, I might be headed down the wrong approach! The end goal is for FormA to create a record, and FormB to create a record, then do something with that record.

FormA should validate that the contents of the record are created appropriately. FormB should validate that FormA is valid, and then that the record can be used.


For exact context, FormA is creating a "label" record on my database, and FormB is printing a physical label using the label record on a specific printer.

Comment: If you want to validate the forms at Backend then according to my knowledge, it’s not possible. But there’s another way out. You can just remove the form tag and do validation using JavaScript, for example button1 is clicked check field1 and if the button2 is clicked check both fields. Or if you really want to do that at back end, you can just use AJAX.

Comment: @ArchitGargi, your suggestion worked. (Happy to accept an answer if provided!).

Instead of attempting to build two forms, a single form was built containing two submit buttons.

Within the form, field2 is marked as non-required, so when btn1 is submitted, the value of field2 is ignored.

However, when btn2 is clicked, clientside javascript is ran to check that field2 is provided (even though it is not required). If no input has been provided, `preventDefault` and notify the user that the form cannot be submitted until the missing field is populated.

Comment: @Asa Happy to hear my suggestion helped.